# How to add two, three or more JTables with one JButton

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Please help me. I have one JButton and one JTextField in my programm. By clicking the button one tab is created whith the name printed in JTextField with one JTable inside this tab. Clicking the button again with another name in JTextField I need to create another tab with another JTable in this new tab but after doing this JTable in the first tab becomes empty and all info from the first tab comes to the second tab. Guess it is because my DefaultTableModel has one name. I don't know how to generate DefaultTableModel name dynamically. Is it possible?

Here is my code for JButton:

```
private void bt_AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    GlobalVars.firmAdd = tf_addFirm.getText();
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    tableModel.setDataVector(new Object [][] {}, new String [] {"№", "Дата заказа", "Дата статуса", "Наименование детали", "Оборудование", "Ссылка для фото", "Кол-во", "Номер заказа", "Стоимость", "Срок поставки", "Согласовано", "В обработке", "Сбор заказа", "Заказано"});
    if (table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(40);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(40);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(80);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(80);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(80);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(300);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(300);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(300);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(300);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(300);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(300);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMinWidth(200);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(200);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMaxWidth(200);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMinWidth(50);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(50);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMaxWidth(50);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMinWidth(150);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(150);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMaxWidth(150);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setMinWidth(95);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(95);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setMaxWidth(95);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setMinWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setMaxWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setMinWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setMaxWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setMinWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setPreferredWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setMaxWidth(85);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setMinWidth(65);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setPreferredWidth(65);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setMaxWidth(65);
            table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
            table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
        }
    tb_tabbedPane.addTab(GlobalVars.firmAdd, new JScrollPane(table));
}
```

Comment: Best if you could create and post in your question a valid [mcve] program, one that shows us your problem immediately. Please check the link as well as the [ask].

Comment: And as for your direct question, "is it possible to generate a DefaultTableModel dynamically?", of course yes it is. The question I have is why isn't your code working? And for that, please read the links that I've given you above.

Comment: `after doing this JTable in the first tab becomes empty and all info from the first tab comes to the second tab.` - code you posted looks reasonable (indicating the problem is somewhere else and why you should post an MCVE with every question). You are creating new instances of the TableModel, JTable and JScrollPane so there is no reason for the first tab to become empty. Each tab should contain unique components.

Comment: Why do you have an if statement in your code? You are hardcoding the model to have 13 columns so won't the condition always be true. To minimize the code a little you may want to just set the preferred width, then you use setResizable( false ) on the TableColumns, which will save you setting the min/max width as well.

Comment: When making the MCVE, please remove 12 of the 14 table columns, as well as cruft that sets minimum, preferred & maximum column size. Include **only** what is needed to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. The problem is solved. There was a mistake in my code.